# Как сделать чтобы Поле2 реагировало на обновления(изменения) Поле1?

Tags: access, vba, visual-basic

Сценарий:

1. ПолеСпец. Вводим "1" + нажимаем "Ввод";
2. Поле1. Цифра "1" попадает в Поле1;
3. Поле2. Цифра "1" из Поле1 суммируется с существующим значением из Поле2 (т.е. Поле2 + Поле1);

Код (условно)

```
Private Sub cmb_1_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
        If KeyCode = 13 Then
                      Поле1 = cmb_1.Text
        End If
End Sub

    Private Sub Поле1_AfterUpdate()
        Поле1 = Поле1 + Поле1
    End Sub
```

**Вопрос**
Как сделать чтобы **Поле2** реагировало именно на появление новой цифры(не важно совпадает ли она с предыдущей цифрой) в **Поле1** и потом выполнялась необходимая операция?
Т.е. главное соблюсти механику без изменения п.1 и п.2 сценария и кода для выполнения этого сценария.

Файл - [ссылка](http://transfiles.ru/6mxau)

**Рисунок**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Зачем реагировать на обновление другого поля? Все в одной процедуре

```
Private Sub cmb_1_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
    Поле1 = cmb_1.Text

    If Not IsNumeric(Поле2) Then
        Поле2 = Val(cmb_1.Text)
    Else
        Поле2 = Val(cmb_1.Text) + Val(Поле2)
    End If
End Sub
```